# NHibernate: How to filter mapped collection based on discriminator type

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

**Info:** 
There is a group object. Users can be invited to groups. There are two types of group invitations: external and internal. All invites are stored in single table using discriminator. The group object knows only about internal invites.

**Problem** In the Invite table there are two records. One for internal and one for external. If I load the group I will see both invites even the collection is of type InternalInvite. [image: InternalInvite result].

```
SELECT internalin0_.Group_id as Group3_1_,
   internalin0_.Id       as Id1_,
   internalin0_.Id       as Id0_0_,
   internalin0_.Group_id as Group3_0_0_,
   internalin0_.User_id  as User5_0_0_
```

FROM   [AbstractInvite] internalin0_
WHERE  internalin0_.Group_id = 'be60b160-659e-4157-b033-9f9e00e346c7'

When I change the ISet collection type to AbstractInvite it will load all invites with the correct type.

**Question** How can I map the collection property to only InternalInvites?

I will try to minimize the code as much as I can.

**The group and the group mapping:**

```
public class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
        InternalInvitations = new HashedSet<InternalInvite>();
    }
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<InternalInvite> InternalInvitations { get; set; }
}

public class GroupMap : ClassMap<Group>
{
    public GroupMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(x => x.InternalInvitations).Inverse();
    }
}
```

**The external and internal invite + mappings:**

```
public abstract class AbstractInvite
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class ExternalInvite : AbstractInvite
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }     
}

public class InternalInvite : AbstractInvite
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class AbstractInviteMap : ClassMap<AbstractInvite>
{
    public AbstractInviteMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.Group);
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("type");
    }
}

public class ExternalInviteMap : SubclassMap<ExternalInvite>
{
    public ExternalInviteMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}

public class InternalInviteMap : SubclassMap<InternalInvite>
{
    public InternalInviteMap()
    {
        References(x => x.User);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work. Please post the SQL query that is executed when you access the collection.

Comment: I added the SQL query in the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer to myself.

I was able to achieve my goal with the code below:

```
public class AbstractInviteMap : ClassMap<AbstractInvite>
{
    public AbstractInviteMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.Group);
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("type").AlwaysSelectWithValue();
    }
}
```

Reference: [Discriminator in NHibernate documentation. Focus on 'force' option.](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-discriminator)

Answer (score 1):

a quickfix/workaround would be

```
HasMany(x => x.InternalInvitations).Inverse().Where("type = 'Namespace.InternalInviteMap'");
```

Comment: This is my current setup. The where clause works just fine for the moment but I think it is not correct.